# Paperclip throwing NilClass error for .first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

**Ruby version: 2.0**

**Rails version: 4.0**

I have a Gallery class - that `has_many :assets` (assets being a model that accepts uploads from `Paperclip`)

I am attempting to display a thumbnail image for each gallery in the index. I want to do something like:

`<%= gallery.assets.first.photo.url(:thumb) %>`

However, that gives me this error: `undefined method`photo' for nil:NilClass`

**Here's the weird part:**

This works:

```
<% gallery.assets.each do |asset| %>
    <%= image_tag asset.photo.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

But I only want one image - not all of them. What am I missing?

**Update**

Here is the requested console output

**Gallery.first.assets**

```
2.0.0p247 :010 > Gallery.first.assets
  Gallery Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "galleries".* FROM "galleries" ORDER BY "galleries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Asset Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "assets".* FROM "assets" WHERE "assets"."gallery_id" = ?  [["gallery_id", 2]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Asset id: 15, gallery_id: 2, created_at: "2013-08-23 23:12:47", updated_at: "2013-08-23 23:12:47", photo_file_name: "mightywash.png", photo_content_type: "image/png", photo_file_size: 24967, photo_updated_at: "2013-08-23 23:12:46">]> 
2.0.0p247 :011 >
```

**Gallery.first.assets.first**

```
2.0.0p247 :011 > Gallery.first.assets.first
  Gallery Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "galleries".* FROM "galleries" ORDER BY "galleries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Asset Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "assets".* FROM "assets" WHERE "assets"."gallery_id" = ? ORDER BY "assets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["gallery_id", 2]]
 => #<Asset id: 15, gallery_id: 2, created_at: "2013-08-23 23:12:47", updated_at: "2013-08-23 23:12:47", photo_file_name: "mightywash.png", photo_content_type: "image/png", photo_file_size: 24967, photo_updated_at: "2013-08-23 23:12:46"> 
2.0.0p247 :012 >
```

**Update 2**

**asset.rb**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery
    has_attached_file :photo,
        :styles => {
            :thumb => "100x100#",
            :small => "300x300>",
            :large => "600x600>"
        }
end
```

Comment: Can you open a `rails console` and show us the result of both `gallery.assets`and `gallery.assets.first`?

Comment: @Serabe yep - updating now.

Comment: Add `gallery.assets.first.photo`, please.

Comment: @Serabe `NoMethodError: undefined method 'photo' for #<Asset:0x007fde7dc01aa8>`

Comment: Add `Asset` model code, please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36140/discussion-between-serabe-and-anwyatt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect one of your assets may not have a photo stored. Try doing this instead:

```
<%= @gallery.assets.first.photo.url(:thumb) if !@gallery.assets.empty? && @gallery.assets.first.photo  %>
```

or even better put something like this in your gallery model;

```
def thumb_url
  unless assets.empty?
    assets.first.photo.url(:thumb) if assets.first.photo
  end
end
```

and then in your view:

```
<%= @gallery.thumb_url %>
```